# Where is PackageMaker? How can i make package installer?

Tags: macos, cocoa, packagemaker

I'm making Development tool which needs Git, Heroku, Python, Ruby.

So I need package installer to check and install git and heroku toolbelt, if those are not exist.

In my guess, I can use package installer in XCode.

But I can not find package installer in /Development/Utility.

Recently, XCode Development directory was moved in XCode package, so I checked it, but still I cannot find package maker.

1) Where is package maker?
2) Can I install heroku and git with Package Maker?

Comment: To get PackageMaker, open the Xcode menu, select "Open Developer Tool -> More Developer Tools...", then download the "Auxiliary Tools for Xcode" package from the list.

Comment: I had to download the `Auxiliary Tools for XCode - Late July 2012`. Later versions didn't seem to have it.

Comment: To get `PackageMaker`, I also downloaded *Auxiliary Tools for XCode - Late July 2012*.

Answer (score 3):

PackageMaker have been deprecated years ago.

1. As a solution you can try to use it by downloading from the [Apple downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=for%20Xcode),
2. but I recommend you to use command line utility: [productbuild](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productbuild.1.html).
3. Or you can use 3rd party application: [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/PackageMaker_Howto.html)

Answer (score 0):

I once had to update some very old code that was packaged with PackageMaker. 
It was extremely difficult to find on the internet and I eventually only found an old copy stored on the NAS server at my job. No matter where I looked online I could not find a copy.

I archived a copy here: https://github.com/sitting-duck/stuff/tree/master/macOSisWeird/packagemaker

Answer (score 0):

It seems like people still look for PackageMaker, I needed it recently

if it can helps, here is direct link from Apple

[PackageMaker(AuxTools)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/auxiliary_tools_for_xcode__late_july_2012/xcode44auxtools6938114a.dmg)

Answer (score 0):

As i found PackageMaker in a very very old project script of mine.. after a short research in the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues)

> Apple no longer maintains the PackageMaker tool, which doesn’t support code signing. Migrate to **pkgbuild** or **productbuild**, *which incorporate most of the command line options that PackageMaker supported*, or use a third-party utility that wraps pkgbuild or productbuild and supports signing.